# How unlivable could I make a planet, but still have it livable?

Tags: planets, humans, atmosphere, prison

So I wanted to make a prison that is like no other. The planet itself is the prison. Your put on the planet and you serve your sentence and then you get taken back to your home planet. How hellish could the planet be (to make it as unlivable as it could be), but still be survivable for Homo Sapiens?

Comment: It looks like you're asking a question that is more focused on prompting discussion, brainstorming, and generating ideas than resolving some specific answerable issue related to building a world. As written this question is likely to have many equally valid answers which makes this question unsuitable for this site.

Comment: This question at least requires more detail, i.e. what equipment is available to the human, what size of planet, etc. Perhaps it would be helpful to lead the question with a scenario to better focus the question, and then provide parameters to narrow the potential answers.

Comment: You really need more parameters. Bad can mean parasites/fauna, weather, geography, temperature, atmosphere, people, radiation, toxicity, etc. The list is as long as there are things that can kill people. Even a star due to explode within a few years could make being on a planet horrifying.

Answer (score 1):

Make the atmosphere much thicker than the earth’s, resulting in a near-sunless surface and constant high-speed winds, with frequent thunderstorms. Let there be only isolated oases, and most of the land consist of barren, windswept steppe devoid of water. Let the gravity be just high enough to be crippling without actually being lethal, and let carnivorous jellyfish-like creatures drift in the upper atmosphere, ensnaring the unlucky in stinging tentacles before dragging them, screaming and convulsing into the hellish sky. Because of the dense atmosphere, every thunderclap is enough to blow the eardrums asunder.

Let the only edible material be brown desert succulents, bitter-tasting but nutritious. The prisoners are forced to graze on these plants like human sheep, naked and exposed to the elements, until they have served their term. Most are driven mad with fear and hunger and sorrow by the time they are collected by the prison-ships, or are taken by the sky-jellies.

Hellish enough? I may have got carried away ;)

Answer (score 0):

A happy little joke will make your day on a nasty planet more bearable.

There are no livable planets. Here is the proof. Imagine the opposite, that there are some livable planets. Rank order them according to degree of livability. This will allow you to discover the least livable planet. The obvious unlivable nature of this planet means it is not livable, removing it from the list. The projection to an empty list is obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Find yourself a *cool* planet, say average temperature 5-10 degrees Celsius. When temperature varies between -30 and +15, your prisoners tend to behave properly (ref. Siberia)

It would be a nice teaser for the prisoners, if there's volcanism and earthquakes. Some geological activity will come out handy.

The planet gives 2G gravity. Although people will survive 2G, it will make life very fatiguing.

When you founded yourself this prison planet, take into account you won't have enough personnel to guard the place. Make sure your planet doesn't have any natural resources like iron, and no fossil fuels. Only agricultural activity is allowed, their harvest is confisqated and distributed.

The planet has an active sun and a weak upper atmosphere, allowing for just enough solar storms to inhibit any use of electronics on the surface.

Comment: On this site there is an expectation that members [only answer well asked questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Answer%20well%2Dasked,be%20answered%20here). Please don't answer questions that have obvious issues, and instead work with OP to resolve those issues before answering.

Comment: Ah there's mr @sphennings.. well I disagree with you sphennings, and there were only 2 votes for close when I answered this.. I am *not* going to remove my answer, or discuss things with you.. despite the downvotes you invoke with confrontational remarks like the above. Your way of kicking members around is one of the reasons I'm not doing WB on a daily basis anymore. *You have won*. I wish you a happy inquisition.

Comment: Site policy is clear about this. Instead of ignoring it, consider trying to participate in this site as it was designed. Closing questions that aren't well asked is a fundamental part of the SE model. If you're not willing to close questions perhaps this model isn't the best for you.

Comment: @sphennings I haven't said anything about the closure decision. Site policy and peer mod democracy determine the outcome: who am I, to judge that ? My protest refers to your policing answers *after* closure has taken place. Any member is free to answer a question not closed yet and there is no reason to put above negative remarks. Please just comment on my answer content, or don't comment, I feel harassed by you.

Comment: There is no technical limitation on people answering open questions but as is [written in the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Answer%20well%2Dasked,be%20answered%20here) there is an expectation that people only answer well asked questions. *"Not all questions can or should be answered here."* There is a similar expectation that members with sufficient reputation, (like yourself) participate in the voting and closure process.  I have 0 authority to police. I'm just asking you to please follow site policy as outlined in the help center.

Comment: @sphennings I've been here for 20 months or so. The reason I have reputation is that  some answers I put got appreciated by readers. That is all I did to gain that reputation. I don't see any *duty* here and I think you should not "serve" in that way either. Participation is a voluntary creative process. Answerers are NOT employees of Stack Exchange. Not everyone attempts to redact and educate the forum like you do, or agrees with *every* closure decision you initiate here. Accept fhat fact. Please.